# How to get any website xml and json data from webserver in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, xml-parsing

This is my link.....

http://golf.42point5.com.api/Jsonapi.php?method=playingmatch

If i write like this i am getting " null ".
sample code :

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://golf.42point5.com.api/Jsonapi.php?method=playingmatch"];
NSStringEncoding *encoding;
NSError *error;

NSString *myHtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:encoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",myHtml);
```

Comment: `encoding` is set, else it should be used `usedEncoding:&encoding` according to the doc? Also, did you try to check `error` parameter? Did you set the App Transport Security of your app? Also, avoid using `initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` which is synchrone.

Comment: I set app transport security in plist file, and i am not getting any error

Comment: I want to get xml and json data for the above link. How? can u help me?

Comment: In Safari, do you get string? Because, I don't on mine. Missing info? Also, it's seems to be a JSONApi, which seems to be read as "HTML"? Did you miss some info, or hide them on purpose?

Comment: Log `error`. What does it say?